# display picture in jsp

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

i want display pictures using this code

```
    <c:forEach items="${articles}" var="o">
    <tr>
    <td>${o.id}</td>
    <td><div class="media">
        <a class="pull-left" href="#"> 
                         <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" width="100"    src="images/articles/{o.id}.jpeg"
                                            alt="...">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">${o.titre}</h4>
            ${o.description}
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><div class="pull-right">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>${o.date}
        </div>
    </td>
```

note that the name of each picture is the id of the article.jpeg

Comment: You're supposed to ask a question.

Comment: yes the problem is that my code is not working how to concat the name of the folder and the name of image which is ${o.id}.jpeg

Comment: The way you did. Will you finally tell us what the problem is? What do you expect this code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: the pictures are not displayed this is my problem

Comment: You missed the ```$``` sign in your img tags src attribute try ```src="images/articles/${o.id}.jpeg"```. Also check the generated source from your browser.

Comment: +1 to @Karthikeyan. You can easily find these kinds of errors by looking at the generated HTML code in the browser (right-click, view page source)

Comment: @Karthikeyan yes the problem comes from there

Comment: @ JB Nizet thank you for your useful remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
src="images/articles/{o.id}.jpeg"
```

with

```
src="images/articles/${o.id}.jpeg"
```